# How can I make the command (cmd) window in Windows 7 wider?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I would like to make the cmd.exe window wider in Windows 7 so it can display a tracert without wrapping. Is that possible? The window seems to be resizable only in the vertical direction when dragged. If not possible, is there a good reason why there is this limitation?

Answer (score 9):

You can change height and width by right clicking the top border and selecting `defaults`. Navigate to the layout tab and change it from there.

[image]

Comment: The hitch with this is that the command window doesn't auto-resize to this size when you open a new instance. It just gets a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom for you to resize to the width you specified.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps:

- open a cmd window
- right click the title bar
- select **Properties**
- select **Layout** tab
- adjust **Width** under **Buffer size** and **Window size**
- click **OK**

Answer (score 1):

Quick one-off way is using the mode command.

For example

```
 Mode 120,300
```

Should try to show 120 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Powershell. Although slightly wider, it also has a fixed max width, but for most purposes it's wide enough and doesn't wrap words to next line.

Edit:

You can resize Command Prompt or Powershell windows by:

Right click on title bar > Properties > Layout tab.

Here you can specify a new width (default is 80 in Command Prompt and 120 in Powershell).